# ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (Handler)

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia

"webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25"

ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (Handler)

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to include the code that triggered this error?

Comment: Can you also help paste more error message in if you encounter something similar the next time?

Answer (score 1):

[aurelia-logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-logging) released 1.5.1 version that can't be uglified correctly.

1. Patch your package.json with:

   "aurelia-logging":"1.5.0",

Or

```
"aurelia-event-aggregator": "1.0.1",
"aurelia-logging":"1.5.0",
```

if you're using [aurelia-event-aggregator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-event-aggregator) in your webpack config.

(aurelia-event-aggregator has aurelia-logging dependency)

2. Reinstall node_modules.
3. enjoy with webpack